# How to initialize HResult in XAML apps?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

This [Speech recognition quickstart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn630427.aspx) article instructs me to

> ... initialize a global variable (HResultPrivacyStatementDeclined) to the HResult value of 0x80045509

The codes are:

```
private static uint HResultPrivacyStatementDeclined = 0x80045509;
```

and

```
catch (Exception exception)
{
  // Handle the speech privacy policy error.
  if ((uint)exception.HResult == HResultPrivacyStatementDeclined)
  {
    resultTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    resultTextBlock.Text = "The privacy statement was declined. 
      Go to Settings -> Privacy -> Speech, inking and typing, and ensure you 
      have viewed the privacy policy, and 'Get To Know You' is enabled.";
    // Open the privacy/speech, inking, and typing settings page.
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:privacy-accounts")); 
  }
  else
  {
    var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(exception.Message, "Exception");
    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
  }
}
```

But, where are we supposed to place those codes? In **App.xaml.cs**?

Comment: according to the documentation, you catch it *during recognition*, i.e. when you're using the API.

Comment: "We then catch any standard exceptions during recogntion and test if the HResult value is equal to the value of the HResultPrivacyStatementDeclined variable" You put that catch block around any place where you're calling an interface method.